# Trying to create objects and calculate them all value in one go. Getting error in if else statement

Tags: java, object

> First of all just want to say Hi to everyone. Im new to coding
>   and specially to Java. Im trying to practise Java by creating objects
>   from Holiday class to display and calculate them values.
>   I cant figure out how to get all object to be printed in if else statement at
>   once, if I enter individual names it works fine. But what code will be to 
>   calculate them in one go. Thank you

```
package Holiday; 

  public class Service{
   public String name;
   public double cost;
   public double payedOff;


  public static void main(String[] args){

// All servicess go here

Service camera = new Service();
 camera.name = "Camera";
 camera.cost = 1500;
 camera.payedOff = 0;


Service music = new Service();
  music.name = "Music";
  music.cost = 4000;

Service video = new Service();
 video.name = "Video";
 video.cost = 3000;
 video.payedOff = 3000;

Service hotel = new Service();
  hotel.name = "Hotel";
  hotel.cost = 2100;

Service transport = new Service();
 transport.name = "Transport";
 transport.cost = 2000;

Service car = new Service();
 car.name = "Car";
 car.cost = 200;



 if (????.payedOff >= ????.cost){
 System.out.println(????.name + " been payed off");
} else {
  System.out.println(????.name + " still need to pay");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Use a `List<Service>`.

Comment: You'll have to do this for all services. Have a look at [for-loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Should come in handy in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a collection that contains all your Service objects. After you create all your Service objects add them to your list and you can iterate over the list like so

```
ArrayList<Service> allServices = new ArrayList<>();
allServices.add(camera);
allServices.add(music);
allServices.add(video);
allServices.add(hotel);
allServices.add(transport);
allServices.add(car);

for(Service obj : allServices)
    System.out.print(obj.name + " costs " + obj.cost);
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < allServices.size(); i++)
{
   System.out.print(allServices.get(i).name + " costs " + allServices.get(i).cost); 
}
```

Note when i = 0 we are referring to camera since it was the first object we added to our list. i = allServices.size() - 1 is the car object since it was the last object we added to our list.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thank you very much. What i will do is create 2 array lists paid and pay and add every object in relevant list with help of if statement